# Change timezone display in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, timezone, centos7

I have one silly question on how can I change the date-time in CentOS 7 from this format **Thu Jun  4 20:30:43 WIB 2020** to **Thu Jun  4 20:33:43 +07 2020**. Is this possible? By the way, I'm using timedatectl when I installed CentOS 7.

```
# date
Thu Jun  4 20:36:46 WIB 2020
```

change to

```
# date
Thu Jun  4 20:36:46 +07 2020
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your shell's current locale:

```
locale
```

Then edit `date_fmt` variable from the `/usr/share/i18n/locales/$YOUR_LOCALE_HERE` file accordingly to yours. In this case:

```
date_fmt "+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %:z %Y"
```

And rebuild your localisation files again after the change:

```
locale-gen
```

As seen in the [date man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) it seems that by default only the following time zone formats are supported:

```
       %z     +hhmm numeric time zone (e.g., -0400)

       %:z    +hh:mm numeric time zone (e.g., -04:00)

       %::z   +hh:mm:ss numeric time zone (e.g., -04:00:00)

       %:::z  numeric time zone with : to necessary precision (e.g., -04, +05:30)

       %Z     alphabetic time zone abbreviation (e.g., EDT)
```

That means that the previous command will return the following:

```
Thu Jun  4 20:22:47 +02:00 2020
```

However, you can always define a custom `alias` for your `date` command to exactly show as you want to:

```
alias date='date "+%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %:z %Y" |sed "s|:00||"'
```

Add it to your `.bashrc` file or wherever you store your aliases and you should be fine.